# Second table-cell is not aligning to the top

Tags: html, css

I have the following html where I want the left div  to show an image about 20% and the second div to contain text and take up the rest of the width.  The problem I have is the second div gets pushed to the button when the image is added:

```
<div style="display:table; width: 100%; border: solid 1px blue;">

    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 20%;  max-height: 100%; border: solid 1px green; ">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" style=" width: 100%; height: 100%;  border: 0;" />            
    </div>
    <div style="dislay: table-cell; border: solid 1px red; vertical-align: top; top: 0; left: 0; ">
        This is the area of the description
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

This example as you can see pushes the text to the bottom.  But if I remove the image then all is well:

```
<div style="display:table; width: 100%; border: solid 1px blue;">

    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 20%;  max-height: 100%; border: solid 1px green; ">
        No Image        
    </div>
    <div style="dislay: table-cell; border: solid 1px red; vertical-align: top; top: 0; left: 0; ">
        This is the area of the description
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

If I float the image to the left, it behaves properly but the table is not taking the whole width of the browser now

```
<div style="display:table; border: solid 1px blue;">

    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 20%;  max-height: 100%; border: solid 1px green; float: left; ">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" style=" width: 100%; height: 100%;  border: 0;" />            
    </div>
    <div style="dislay: table-cell; border: solid 1px red; vertical-align: top; top: 0; left: 0; ">
        This is the area of the description
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Here is my [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/adviner/kmfkr97t/6/)

I've tried different things but nothing seems to work.  So if anyone can give me any tips, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Typo `dislay: table-cell;` should be `display`.

Comment: OMG, I cant believe it was a mis-spelled word.  Thank you for pointing it out to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add `width:100%` on the bottom div.

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmfkr97t/8/).

It should be like this:

```
<div style="display:table; width: 100%; border: solid 1px blue;">

    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 20%;  max-height: 100%; border: solid 1px green; float: left; ">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" style=" width: 100%; height: 100%;  border: 0;" />            
    </div>
    <div style="dislay: table-cell; border: solid 1px red; vertical-align: top; top: 0; left: 0; ">
        This is the area of the description
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  This fixed it also for the floating of the image.

Comment: You are welcome. I'd be thankful if you upvoted and accepted my answer too. Thanks!